# What are the mathematical or logical differences between these presentations of Peano addition?

Tags: logic, notation

$\def\plus{\operatorname{plus}}$The following represents my understanding and may contain false assumptions.

**(1)**  below represents my understanding the definition of Peano addition as a pair of equations in equational logic. Equations in equational logic are reflexive, symmetric, and transitive, which I believe is required in the axiomization of Peano Numbers.

**(1)**
\begin{align}
    \plus(x,0) &=  x\\
    \plus(x,s(y)) &= s(\plus(x,y))
\end{align}

**(2)** represents my understanding of the definition of Peano addition as a piecewise function with first order logic and equality (FOLEQ). Here I am unsure of the equality in the conditions. It would seem to differ from the equals symbol to the left of the bracket. Perhaps I should use $\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}$?

Also, I am not sure how the case statement in **(2)** fits in with the language of FOLEQ.  Perhaps something like $\forall x,y \in  \mathbb N \colon((y=0) \implies (\plus(x,y) = x))$ for the first case in **(2)** .

**(2)**
\begin{align*}
\forall x,y \in \mathbb N ~\colon \plus(x,y) = \begin{cases}
x & \text{if $y=0$}, \\
s(\plus(x,y'))  & \text{if $y = s(y')$}. \\
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

**Questions:**

Are there flaws or inconsistencies with  **(1)**  and **(2)**?

Could either **(1)** or **(2)** be considered as definitions and/or axioms?

What are the similarities and differences between  **(1)**  and **(2)**.

In what situations would one prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both fine. The first version is the one you will usually find when $\mathsf{PA}$ is formulated as a first-order theory. It corresponds to the two axioms:
$$
  A_0 := \forall x \, (x + 0 = x)\\
  A_1 := \forall x \, \forall y \, ( x + S y = S(x + y))
$$
The second version represents an attempt to put both of these axioms into one formula, i.e. unite them into one axiom:
$$
  A := \forall x \, \forall y \, (y = 0 \to x + y = x) \land (\forall z \, (y = S z \to x + y = S(x +z)))
$$

---

Let $\mathsf{PA}'$ denote the standard axiomatization of $\mathsf{PA}$ but without $A_0$ and $A_1$. So we have $\mathsf{PA} = \mathsf{PA}' + A_0 + A_1$ and we can ask whether
$$
  \mathsf{PA}' + A_0 + A_1 \vdash A ~~~~~~\text{and}~~~~~~
  \mathsf{PA}' + A \vdash A_0 \land A_1
$$
Both are indeed provable, meaning the axioms $A_0$ and $A_1$ can be exchanged for $A$ in $\mathsf{PA}$ and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer. Should $A_s$ be $A_1$?

Comment: @PatrickBrowne Indeed! Fixed it.